# Running Cmake built executables with shared library dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a Cmake executable that has been created using `ADD_EXECUTABLE`.
The executable needs (links to) shared libraries that have been created
also part of the project.

As a final step I want to run this executable as part of the build process to
create some additional files for the build.

so

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT out1 
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY dir1
                   COMMAND foo args
                   ...)
```

However when the custom command runs it gives an error

```
.../foo: error while loading shared libraries: libbar.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [out1]  Error 127

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The problem is that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set for the executable to load the library
`libbar.so.1`. How do in a cross-platform manner set the load library settings in cmake.
I don't want to use RPATH because it actually embeds those paths in the executable, which I
don't want.

Comment: Your problem is a bit strange, by default CMake creates executables with the full rpath to libraries in the build tree and removes rpath when installing them. So the default behavior is what you want... did you changed something about rpath configuration?

Comment: I assume you're linking the library to the executable by specifying the library's target name in target_link_libraries for the executable?

Comment: maybe as you have it, cmake doesn't know that it has to wait for the executable to be re-buitl before running it. You can make it run after the build of the executable by using [the other signature of `add_custom_command()`- the "Build Events signature"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events). Try using it with `POST_BUILD`